# Getting value from associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My setup: Rails 2.3.10, Ruby 1.8.7

Here are my models

```
class User
 has_many :user_projects
end

class Project
 has_many :user_projects
 #has a column named "project_type"
end

class UserProject
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :project
 #fields: project_id, user_id
end
```

When I return a JSON string of a user and his related user_projects records, I also want to include in the user_project record the project.project_type column. Note: I don't want to also include the entire project record in the results. A possible solution is dup the project_type field in user_projects but I prefer not to do that if possible, is there another way to accomplish this during the find/read action?

Just to be clear, here's the JSON output I'm looking for

```
{
  "user": {
    "username": "bob",
    "id": 1,
    "email": "bob@blah.com"
    "user_projects": [
      {
            "id": 15,
            "user_id": 1,
            "project_id": 10,
            "project_type": "marketing"
      }
      {
            "id": 22,
            "user_id": 1,
            "project_id": 11,
            "project_type": "sales"
      }
     ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the `:only` key in a nested include:

```
user.to_json(:include => {:user_projects => {:include => {:project => {:only => :type}}}})
```

But I would add `has_many :projects, :through => :user_projects` to User so you can do the simpler:

```
user.to_json(:include => {:projects => {:only => [:id, :type]}})
```

Also, an off-topic cautionary note: never use 'type' as a column name in Rails unless you are using STI (ie. the project types are ruby subclasses of Project).

-

**Edit**

Here's a way to add `project_type` to UserProject like you want

```
class UserProject
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
  delegate :type, :to => :project, :prefix => true
end

user.to_json(:include => {:user_projects => {:methods => :project_type}})
```

Comment: Good point on not using 'type' as a column, I'm actually not doing that, bad example on my part. I prefer to only return user_projects.user_id, project_id, and project.type columns all in the context within the user_project scope, is there a way to do that? I thought I might be able to use attr_accessor and somehow pull the value from project when a user_project record is being accessed but can't get that to work.

Comment: look my answer, seems it's what you want to achieve

Answer (score 2):

```
class UserProject
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :project
   #fields: project_id, user_id
   attr_reader :type


  def type
    self.project.type
  end
 end

 class MyController < AC

   def action
     @model = whatever
     respond_to do |format|
       format.json { render :json => @model.to_json(:methods => :type)}
     end

   end
 end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this is closer to what I was thinking of doing except that I need to return all the user details and include user_projects plus the type column as part of the user_project details, any idea on syntax?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out, that worked exactly like I hoped, thanks!

Comment: One last note, it needs to be def self.type

Comment: Oops, I spoke too soon, it is show a value of null, so it isn't working

Comment: Pasta: the `attr_reader` line shouldn't be there. Bob: you don't want `def self.type`, that would make it a class method